# Make login via google plus in a WebView

Tags: android, webview, google-plus-signin

I need to use WebView in my android app for viewing some sites. And on sites, it is possible to have a login through google plus. A read several tutorials and in result i have the next code:

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ua.test.testgoogleauth.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/webview_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/my_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FrameLayout webViewFrame;
    private WebView webViewMain;
    private WebView webViewWindow;

    private final String URL = "https://some_url_with_google_auth";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webViewFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.webview_frame);
        webViewMain = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);

        webViewMain.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        webViewMain.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient());
        webViewMain.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webViewMain.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        webViewMain.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewMain.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webViewMain.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webViewMain.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webViewMain.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webViewMain.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webViewMain.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        webViewMain.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webViewMain.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webViewMain.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webViewMain.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webViewMain.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        webViewMain.loadUrl(URL);
    }


    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private class CustomWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                      boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            webViewWindow = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
            webViewWindow.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            webViewWindow.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            webViewWindow.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
            webViewWindow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webViewWindow.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            webViewFrame.addView(webViewWindow);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(webViewWindow);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
            webViewFrame.removeView(webViewWindow);
            webViewWindow = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webViewWindow != null) {
            webViewFrame.removeView(webViewWindow);
            webViewWindow = null;
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

And always after click auth button i have error: "Error: disallowed_useragent". I read tutorials , but there is no solving for this problem. 
So, help me please, how to resolve this error? If i must use google plus sdk for auth, how to send user token to webview? Or is there another solution?

Comment: I am not sure but I think you are missing user agent from your webivew configuration. Follow this link and add a suitable user agent to your webview. https://mobiforge.com/research-analysis/webviews-and-user-agent-strings

Comment: I tried to add many variants of useragents but it doesnt work :(

Answer (score -1):

As written here in 2016 :
https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

> In the coming months, we will no longer allow OAuth requests to Google
>   in embedded browsers known as “web-views”

So you have to use Google sign in api.

Comment: Hm ... But if i want to use webview to surf some sites with google auth ? Is there no way to make it? Or maybe can I use google auth and then give the user token to the webview for further processing?